# Mouse scroll wheel works selectively in Ubuntu VM

Tags: mouse, qemu, 22.10

I'm getting an odd issue in my Ubuntu 22.10 virtual machine running in Proxmox.

My mouse is a Razer wired mouse that's showing up in Ubuntu as "VirtualPS/2 VMWare VMMouse"

In Settings > Mouse & Touchpad, the scroll wheel *is* recognized and works properly when I "test my settings." However, it doesn't work in any other application, including terminal, Firefox, etc.

Elsewhere, I found information that I should use `xev` in the terminal. In `xev`, every single button on my mouse (including clicking the scroll wheel) is recognized properly, but nothing is registered on scroll.

I'm a bit confused about where to go next... I can't figure out why `xev` doesn't see my scroll wheel but the Mouse & Touchpad control panel somehow recognizes it.

Any pointers on where to turn next to get my scroll wheel working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with web browsers in particular, after I realized that mouse scroll worked in desktop windows but not in Brave or Firefox.

Reinstalling Firefox did the trick on that browser.

On Brave, I needed to go to brave://flags and change the "Preferred Ozone platform" setting from "Default" to "Auto." I realized as I was fumbling around that Ubuntu was using XWayland, which I believe Brave was not using by default, leading it to ignore scroll wheel input? Or something.